# setting class attributes in class call

Tags: python, class

I am just wondering if there is a shortcut to setting default attributes.
I generally would do

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, att1='X'):
         self.att1 = att1
```

Is there a shortcut in the lines off

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, self.att1='X'):
```

I assume at the moment of the call, the object does not exist, so seem logical that this way does not work, but maybe there is sort of less verbose way to deal with this when there is a lot more attributes to be set.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. Can't you just do `self.att1 = 'X'`, or am I missing the point

Comment: @Haidro: default value. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters What does that mean ;3?

Comment: @Haidro http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: @glglgl Ah, I get what the question's saying now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
class class1(object):
    att1='X'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Comment: This cannot be applied if you want to use (e.g.) `__slots__`. Also it allow the user to add/change whichever attribute in the instance.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely nice to know. In my case, I still want to limit attributes just it is easier to deubg as otherwise, typos sneak in quickly when calling the object